# Javascript dragenter and dragleave events to not fire when dragging over a child

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have the following fiddle which hopefully should help me explain what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/czh6efx7/4/

The following HTML and styles

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">

  </div>
</div>

<div id="draggable" draggable="true"></div>

#a {
  background: green;
  padding: 25px;
}

#b {
  background: red;
  padding: 50px;
}

#draggable {
  padding: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

And the script to accompany that

```
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('dragenter', function(e) {
    if(e.target.id === 'a') {
        console.log("DRAG ENTER");
    }
});

document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('dragleave', function(e) {
    if(e.target.id === 'a') {
        console.log("DRAG LEAVE");
    }
});
```

I have added the `if(e.target.id === 'a') {` check to try to fix this issue but it doesn't seem to work how I thought it should.

Anyway, the exact issue I'm having is that `#b` is a child of `#a` and I don't want the drag events to fire whenever `#draggable` is dragged first to `#a` then to it's child (`#b`). This isn't the case with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, so it appears that `dragenter` and `dragleave` work differently to those.

You should be able to see this on the fiddle provided with the following replication steps:

- Start dragging the blue box
- Drag the blue box over the outside of the green box
  -- See that `DRAG ENTER` is logged, this is fine
- Keep dragging now into the red box 
  -- See that `DRAG LEAVE` is logged, this is not fine as the red box is a child of the green box, so as far as I'm concerned for what I'm trying to achieve, we're still dragged over the green box, albeit a child of the green box.

  - Drag back into the green box from the red box
    -- See that `DRAG ENTER` is fired again, again not ideal since as far as I'm concerned, the user had already entered the drag state for the green box.

My intention is to have this only log `DRAG ENTER` when the user drags onto `#a` and `DRAG LEAVE` when the user drags away from `#a`, regardless of whether it drags over a child of `#a`.

I should also mention that these child elements of `#a` will be interactive so I can't use `mouse-events: none;` to work around this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I can see the usefulness of `dragenter` and `dragleave` being fired on inner child, but it is tricky in your case where you want to have other elements inside.

Could you use `dragover` instead and then detect whether the event is being fired after a certain time? For example:

```
const $a = document.getElementById('a');

const enterHandler = ($a) => { console.log('enter a') };
const leaveHandler = ($a) => { console.log('leave a') };

let timer = null;
$a.ondragover = (e) => {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  enterHandler($a);
  timer = setTimeout(() => leaveHandler($a), 100);
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eguhbr90/